# Web Publish activity/ Local Debugging fails after upgrading from VS 2012 to VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I get the following error : The operation cannot be completed because BeginBuild has not yet been called. Also made changes to upgrade from MVC 4 to MVC 5 using the following url

[http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOWRd.png)

[image: Missing piece in VS 2013 it was there in 2012]

I also cannot run it on IIS Express since it gives me following error

Server Error in '/' Application.

Access is denied. 
  Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009

Comment: One issue is resolved : http://aspdotnerd.blogspot.com/2012/11/error-message-4012-unauthorized-logon.html . By doing the local debugging . But publishing still fails

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from VS.NET 2010 to VS.NET 2013. Debug had worked for ASP.NET running with VS.NET 2010 with the workspace defined on a network drive. After switching to VS.NET 2013, attempts to run debug only produced various server errors that included the text of "Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.".

To resolve this issue, the workspace was changed from a network drive to a local drive on the development server. That made the server errors go away when the ASP.NET website was run using debug.